# Call jQuery from JavaScript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a novice with JavaScript/jQuery, so sorry if my question is simple.

I have the following HTML which calls for jQuery routines:

```
   <div class="global-actions">
      <div class="left-action" id="prev"><img src="resources/previous.png" width="28" height="28"/></div>
      <div class="top-action" id="flipper"><img src="resources/flip.png" width="28" height="28"/></div>
      <div class="right-action" id="next"><img src="resources/next.png" width="28" height="28"/></div>
  </div>
```

Here jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // FLIP
  $('#flipper').bind('click', function(){
    $('.card.current').toggleClass('flip');
  });

  // CYCLE
  $('#deck').cycle({
    after:   onAfter,
    before:  onBefore,
    fx:      'shuffle',
    next:    '#next',
    prev:    '#prev',
    shuffle: {
      top:   -300,
      left:  20
    },
    speed:   'fast',
    timeout: 0,
  });
  function onBefore(){
    $(this).parent().find('.current').removeClass('current');
  }
  function onAfter(){
    $(this).addClass('current');
  }
});
```

I want the images call with a onclick command JavaScript code (see below) which then calls the "prev" and "next" actions, so to say a intermediate layer (objective: add some JavaScript operations before performing the "prev" and "next" routines).

```
<img onclick="javascript:callIntermediatePrev()" src="resources/previous.png" /> 
<img onclick="javascript:callIntermediateNext()" src="resources/next.png" />
```

Comment: Since you are a novice, I suggest to already stop using "inline" listeners added directly to HTML, like `onclick="nameOfFunction"`, instead add the listeners directly on javascript by using `.addEventListener()`, `.on()` or `.onclick = function()...` its much more readable and maintable

Comment: Also, I don't know which version of jQuery you are using, but `.bind()` is deprecated in versions 3.0 and above

Comment: Also, you've never needed `javascript:` before event handlers in attributes. Those were only ever needed when using `<a href="javascript:doSomething()"`, which is rightfully deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this create this script with your image id selector

```
$( "#prev" ).click(function() {
   // here paste the code to switch your image to the prev image
});
$( "#next" ).click(function() {
   // here paste the code to switch your image to the next image
});
```